# Change product dimension label for length in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some custom code that creates a shortcode in Wordpress/Woocommerce that I use to display the product dimensions (**Length**, **Width**, **Height**) - the output works fine however I would like to change the label for '**Length**' to read '**Depth**' (front end only is fine) and re-order the output to display as **Height**, **Width**, **Depth** (in that order)

Here is my code to create the shortcode - however, I am unsure what I need to do to change the output label & to re-order them.

```
add_shortcode( 'product_taxonomies', 'product_taxonomies_shortcode' );
function product_taxonomies_shortcode( $atts ){
    // Shortcode Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_taxonomies' );

    $product_id = ! empty($atts['id']) ? $atts['id'] : 0;

    if( $product_id > 0 ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    } else {
        global $product;
    }

    if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {

        ob_start();

        // Weight
        if ( $product->has_weight() ) {
            $weight_unit = get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit');
            $weight_html = '<strong>'.__("Weight").':</strong> ' . $value . $weight_unit;
            echo '<div class="dimensions">' . $weight_html . '</div>';
        }

        // Dimensions
        if ( $product->has_dimensions() ) {
            $dimension_unit = get_option('woocommerce_dimension_unit');
            $dimensions     = array();
            foreach( $product->get_dimensions( false ) as $key => $value ) {
                if( ! empty($value) )
                    $dimensions[] = '<strong>'.ucfirst($key).':</strong> ' . $value . $dimension_unit;
            }
            echo '<div class="dimensions">' . implode('<br>', $dimensions) . '</div>';
        }

        
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem-space

First, let's identify the code-range where you need to perform your changes:

```
        $dimensions     = array();
        foreach( $product->get_dimensions( false ) as $key => $value ) {
            if( ! empty($value) )
                $dimensions[] = '<strong>'.ucfirst($key).':</strong> ' . $value . $dimension_unit;
        }
        echo '<div class="dimensions">' . implode('<br>', $dimensions) . '</div>';
```

## Perform the changes

```
        $keys = [
            'Height' => 0,
            'Width' => 0,
            'Depth' => 0
        ];
        $dimensions     = array();
        foreach( $product->get_dimensions( false ) as $key => $value ) {
            if( ! empty($value) ) {
                $currentKey = (($key === 'Length') ? 'Depth' : $key);
                $dimensions[$keys[$currentKey]] = '<strong>'.ucfirst($currentKey).':</strong> ' . $value . $dimension_unit;
            }
        }
        echo '<div class="dimensions">' . implode('<br>', $dimensions) . '</div>';
```

## Explanation

- We map the metrix to their desired array-index, so the array will be build in the correct order instead of having it reordered
- We replace 'Length' with 'Depth' if that's the `$key`, otherwise use the `$key`, any replacement being done on the representation level

## Potential problem

I assumed some concrete key values. If my understanding of them is wrong, then some incorrect values might cause troubles. If that's the case, let's discuss the situation you might arrive to.

Comment: Superb, thank you - it's kind of worked :) Height is now displayed first but width and depth(length) is now missing/not displayed

Comment: @Combined then there is some textual difference. Can you somehow find out what the values of $key are, including whitespaces? It might be a space at the start/end of length or Length might be length and so one. I need to know the exact string of the Length key.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've worked it out doing it another way

```
function display_product_dimensions( $atts ){
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_dimensions' ) );

    if( $id == '' ) {
        global $product;

        if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
        }
    }

    return method_exists( $product, 'get_dimensions' ) ? wc_format_dimensions($product->get_dimensions(false)) : '';
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'Custom_formated_product_dimentions_with_labels', 10, 2 );
function Custom_formated_product_dimentions_with_labels( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    if ( empty( $dimension_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    // Set here your new array of dimensions based on existing keys/values
    $new_dimentions = array(
        '<b>Height:</b>' => $dimensions['height'],
        '<b>Width:</b>'  => $dimensions['width'],
        '<b>Depth:</b>' => $dimensions['length']
    );

    $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $new_dimentions ) );

    $label_with_dimensions = array();

    foreach( $dimensions as $key => $dimention ){
        $dimensions[$key] = ucfirst($key) . ' ' . $dimention . ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );
    }

    return implode( ' <br> ',  $dimensions) . '';
}
```

This seems to work and display correctly...

Answer (score -3):

I know it's not directly what you were asking for, maybe even off topic on a developer forum. But I wanted to provide a second option: a plugin that allows you to alter strings on your site without editing WordPress core.

I guess there is a lot of  those plugins out there, but one I like is one called [**Say What**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/)

Best of luck!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28703769)

Comment: You might be interested in this discussion from meta: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/)

Comment: @Brian Well written piece, really enjoyed that one. I think I’m definitely more in line now. Thanks again!